# How to exclude mist from sky/background?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I want to add some atmospheric fog to my scene, the problem is, the mist effect completely covers the sky. How can I exclude the sky from the mist?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope you've found the answer by now. I was trying to do the same as you and spent sometime testing methods to remove the sky from mist pass and this is how I've done it, in case there's someone else looking for this:

The easiest way is by enabling **Transparent Film** in **render properties** tab, then in the compositor, use the Alpha pass from your image/render layer as a factor for a Mix Node (add) between the mist pass and the original image(that will exclude the sky from the mist pass). After that, you Mix the envoirement with the result from the previous node.

Another way i've found, if you don't want to use transparent film, is to get the own envoirement pass, add a Color ramp and try to manually clamp values to 0 or 1 (Black and white), then use the result as a factor for the mist.

Here's my node setup:[image]